# Taking Back Up Of SharePoint Sub site and Restoring in to another Sub site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have a SharePoint Sub site , I want to take the back up of the Sub site and want Restore in to another Sub site of different Site collection, The site collection is belongs to different web application.

Is it Possible through Power shell Command?.

Please Help Me

Comment: Check this link - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/145677/8068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do it via powershell, But you have to make sure both web application have same set of features / solutions etc.

Follow the below powershell commands.

- use [export-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) to export the subsite.`export-spweb -identity "http://Subsite url" -path c:\export.cmp`
- Now create a blank subsite on target site collection. Use [new-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607579.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) powershell. `New-SPWeb http://somesite/subweb1`
- Finally, you have to run the [import-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) to import the subsite. `import-spweb -identity "http://Targetsubsite url" -path "c:\export.cmp"`